# NextAuth - Doesn't redirect to callback url but stays on the singin page

Tags: authentication, next.js, server-side-rendering, next-auth

I am working on nextjs & nextauth projects, with a custom sign-in page. Below are the configurations

Package.json

```
"next": "^12.0.8"
"next-auth": "^4.2.1"
```

[..nextauth].js

```
pages:{
  signIn:'/auth/signin'
},
callbacks: {
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      console.log('redirect : '+url+' : '+baseUrl);
      if (url.startsWith(baseUrl)) return url
      // Allows relative callback URLs
      else if (url.startsWith("/")) return new URL(url, baseUrl).toString()
      return baseUrl;
    }
  }
```

I have a middleware in my profile folder, this is done to secure the files inside this folder. Which should be visible only when user signin.

Folder Structure :

[image]

_middleware.js

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware"
```

Issue : When i try to open the files inside profile folder, it shows the signin screen(working as expected) after successfully signing in the page doesn't redirect to callback url, it still stays on the signin page.

Comment: Can you show us how you're calling `signIn` from the client code?

Comment: here you go -  <button className="uppercase h-12 mt-3 text-white w-full rounded bg-red-700 hover:bg-red-800" onClick={() => signIn("google")}>
                            <i className="fa fa-google mr-2"></i>
                        Google
                        </button>

Comment: Should be onClick={() =>
                            signIn(provider.id, {
                              callbackUrl: '/some-path',
                              password: password,
                              email: email,
                            })
                          }

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem? I'm having the same issues.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have this

```
pages:{
  signIn:'/auth/signin'
},
```

if you are on the "Cart" page and you are redirected to signin from "Cart" page, this "Cart" page will be on the query as `callback=urlfromRedirected`. So you have to catch it, after sign in you have to route it to callback. And when redirecting starts, `redirect` callback will intervene. catch the `callbackUrl` in `getServerSideProps`

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { req, query } = context;
  const session = await getSession({ req });
  const { callbackUrl } = query;
  if (session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: callbackUrl,
      },
    };
  }
  
  return {
    props: {
      callbackUrl,
    },
  };
}
```

If there is not session, we pass the `callbackUrl` to the component and in `signInHandler` you run this

```
 return Router.push(callbackUrl || "/");
```